# What is the grammar used in "[somebody] best girl"?

Tags: grammar, slang

I see on some anime communities for example sometimes people use "[somebody] best girl", meaning "I love her; She is so adorable to me; (or literally) She is the best girl;".

So what is the grammar used in this kind of sentence? I mean is it a legit grammar, or an abbreviation form (of "She is the best girl"), or an informal (incorrect) grammar? And so, can I use for example "You know, Python best language." (= "Python is the best langauge")?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It is, but the ‘slang’ tag exists. I’ve added an edit (that should show up soon). I do think it’s slightly off-topic, but still overall fine for this site.

Comment: umm I don't understand the downvote(s). I cannot see comments deleted but. Isn't here a English language quetion-answering community? at least I desire if you're not content to the content you should give him a hint so I can improve how/what to ask, or no change I can make. And side note, I do not know the sentence is a slang or not. That's why I'm asking here. I'm not a native nor a C2 English speaker.

Comment: Speakers of English will adopt the characteristics of people who don't speak English that well to be funny or to mock someone else's intelligence. "All your base belong to us" "Me love you long time", etc. Use this slang broken English only among communities that will understand the humor. Otherwise, you'll be thought of as someone who can't speak English well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slang usage that, as far as I'm aware, only exists in certain internet circles similar to the ones you've observed it in.

It is intentionally ungrammatical and meant to sound "cutesy." Watch out for many other unique turns of phrase like this in your anime communities, and I advise against trying to spread them to the wider world unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: Isn't slang a part of language? Why questioning slang here is no-go? What can I do when I cannot find any resource or definition or dictionary and cannot ask nowhere?

Comment: @pupsozeyde There's nothing wrong with slang provided the setting is appropriate. Anime slang isn't something people expect to hear outside anime circles, even assuming they're familiar with it at all (ask a group of people over 40 and almost none of them will have a clue), so you should expect some weird looks.